# Android Development: How To Get All EditText Children of a ViewGroup?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, children

Basically, I have a LinearLayout that holds a random amount of horizontal LinearLayouts, and in each of the horizontal LinearLayouts there's a TextView and an EditText. I want to be able to get the value of each EditText children of the master LinearLayout.

Sorry if it's confusing, I'm no good at explaining things!

Could I just set the same ID for each of the EditTexts then use findViewById, or would that only return the first instance of an EditText?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to call findViewById on each of the LinearLayouts. If you do this, you can set the same ID for each EditText.

Comment: Thanks, that's helped, but the problem is now how do I get the text of the EditTexts? I've tried getText() but it doesn't work as the EditText I'm referring to is a View

Comment: call ((EditText)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.someId)).getText().toString()

Comment: It force closes with a NullPointerException :(

Comment: That means it can't find your view. How are you adding the EditTexts? Can you post your code?

Comment: It doesn't matter now, it's because I forgot that there's a TextView before the horizontal LinearLayouts, and I was trying to look for the EditText in that TextView. I'm a poor programmer at times. It's easily solved anyway. Big thanks for your help James :D!

Answer (score 6):

```
 LinearLayout ll = //Your Layout this can be any Linear or Relative layout 
                     //in which you added your spinners at runtime ;

    int count = ll.getChildCount();
    for(int i =0;i<count;i++)
    {
        View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof Spinner)
        {
            // you got the spinner
            EditText s = (EditText) v;
            Log.i("Item selected",s.getText().toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`findViewById` returns only the first view with the given id. You're going to have to traverse the view hierarchy yourself, at least until you get down to each horizontal linear layout. You'll find the methods `ViewGroup.getChildCount()` and `ViewGroup.getChildAt(int)` useful for this.

Comment: Since each child view is also an instance of view, findViewById can be invoked on the child layout which will only traverse its child layouts.

Comment: @James - Yes, I think that's what I said.

Comment: If a found view is an instance of a ViewGroup, you are possible to iterate of those children to. This way you can drilldown your complete view hierarchy and the only thing you have to know is your root layout id. I'm not sure what the performance consequences are for this method. If it is not to much work, you should use the answer of James. This makes it possible to make adaptions to all of your textviews later on in an easy and good performing way.