# Programmatically-loaded XML gives nullpointers?

Tags: android, android-layout

**Basically**: An xml file that gets programmatically loaded into another layout gives me "null pointers"... but only some of the time.

**More specifically**: parent.xml looks like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout >

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout" >

    <!-- 2 columns -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/table_header" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:text="Number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/attached_title"
            android:text="Info" />

        <!-- ******* 1 **********************-->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row_1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/num1"
                android:text="1"/>

            <RelativeLayout>
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView_1">
                </ListView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

    <!-- ****** 2 ****************-->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row_2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/num2"
            android:text="2"/>

        <RelativeLayout>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView_2>
            </ListView>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

child.xml looks like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout>


    <!-- ********* Module ***************************-->
        <RelativeLayout>
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/chc"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextResult_name">
            </EditText>
        </RelativeLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
      </ScrollView>
```

In the activity that uses these xml files, I call the populate() method from onStart:

```
private void populate(Thing thing, int num){
    ListView listView = findListViewByNum(num);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, thing, num);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here's what I want to do, but what doesn't work. I have tried to call this code at the bottom of onStart(), after all the calls to populate() have completed. As far as I understand, at this point all of the views should be inflated, and the activity should have access to the XML elements as I am using them here:

```
public void disable(View v){
  ListView curr = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_1);
  EditText name = (EditText) curr.findViewById(R.id.editTextResult_name);

  Spinner chc = (Spinner) curr.findViewById(R.id.chc);
  String type = chc.getSelectedItem().toString(); // null pointer here.

  if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("DISABLED")){
    name.setEnabled(false);
  }
}
```

Oddly, the *exact* same code is called later, after a button press, and it works fine then. It only doesn't work when I call it directly.

Here's the same stuff, but it works:

```
public void editt1(View v){
  ListView curr = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_1);
  Spinner chc = (Spinner) curr.findViewById(R.id.chc); // finds the right thing
  String type = chc.getSelectedItem().toString(); // no null pointer
  doThing(1, type);
```

}

**What doesn't work**: in disable(), name, and chc are both null, leading to a nullpointer where I've indicated it.

**What I've read**:

- Looks like I'm getting a similar issue to this guy: [How to load programmatically a layout XML file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022615/how-to-load-programmatically-a-layout-xml-file-in-android) , but he's using an expandableListView, which explains why the elements he's attempting to access aren't available. Mine really *are* visible... also the exact code works later, in response to a button press, so I'm stuck. As far as I can tell, the answer by Ryan is exactly what I'm doing up there, in disable.
- Do I need to do something to get "through" the Relative layout that is wrapped around the EditText element? If so, why didn't I need to do that in the other part of my code? Got that idea from this: [Android Development: How To Get All EditText Children of a ViewGroup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638670/android-development-how-to-get-all-edittext-children-of-a-viewgroup)
- Obviously the best question on Mathematica: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66538/how-do-i-draw-a-pair-of-buttocks

**My questions**:

- I'm expecting that, once everything's drawn on the screen, my code should have pretty much complete access to every XML element. Is that incorrect?
- Do I need to deal differently with "nested" structures, such as the EditText inside of the RelativeLayout inside of the Table?
- Why doesn't it work??

***** EDIT *****

Adding CustomAdapter code on request:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

private Thing thing;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private EditText name;
private Spinner chc;
private Context context;
private View row;

public CustomAdapter(Activity context, Thing thing) {
  super();
  this.thing = thing;
  this.inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
  this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
  row = convertView;
  if (row == null){
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child, parent, false);
  }

  name = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editTextResult_name);
  name.setText(thing.getName());

  chc = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.chc);
  ArrayAdapter chcAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) chc.getAdapter();

  int spinnerPosition =    chc_adapter.getPosition(thing.pos));
  chc.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
  chc.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);

  return row;

}

private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener = new   
                       AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
  String chosen = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

  if (chosen.equalsIgnoreCase("blank")){}

    // this doesn't work
    Toast.makeText(context, "name: "+ name.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(context, "before nameText isenabled: "+ name.isEnabled(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    name.setEnabled(false);
    name.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    Toast.makeText(context, "after nameText isEnabled: "+ name.isEnabled(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  } else {
    makeControllerButtonVisible(selected, port);

    //this part doesn't work, not sure why.
    Toast.makeText(context, "name: "+ name.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(context, "before name isEnabled: "+ name.isEnabled(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    name.setEnabled(true);
    name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    Toast.makeText(context, "after name isEnabled: "+ name.isEnabled(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
};


}
```

Comment: getSelectedItem returns null if nothing is selected

Comment: Your first ListView has the id listView_port1 but you are trying to access it using R.id.listview_1. This isn't the answer to your problem just need some clarification.

Comment: But "chc" itself is null - not the result of calling chc.getItemSelected(). See what I mean?

Comment: @zgc7009 thanks for the catch, but that's only true in this example version I've posted. I'll edit it now - the name is correct in the source code.

Comment: When do you add child.xml to your layout? It seems you are trying to access views in the layout before you actually add it to your parent layout.

Comment: child.xml gets loaded via the custom adapter mentioned in populate().. and yeah that was my thought too. At one point I added a button that calls disable(), and when a human pushes it, it works, but when I programmatically push it at the end of onStart, it fails.

Comment: Is there any way you could post the code from the adapter where child.xml is utilized?

Comment: Ahh I see, each of your list items has the layout child.xml. What is happening is that your adapter is only calling getView when a new list item becomes visible (this isn't exactly in sync with your activity's life cycle). You could send a broadcast from getView once it is called that a receiver you create in your activity receives to know that the views are inflated and ready to work with. Do note I would do something differently (allowing getView in my adapter to actually handle things). I would be happy to post a more thorough response as an answer if you need help.

Comment: I would LOVE a more thorough response. I'm super new to this and feel like I'm hacking things together with no real understanding, so I'd love to learn a better way!